# How to save strings in array after tokenizing it c++?

Tags: c++, boost

My input.txt file looks like this.

```
"55.2""4""1""0""d""e""a"
```

So I wrote small cpp to tokenize it with boost.

```
#include <iostream>     // cout, endl
#include <fstream>      // fstream
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>    // copy
#include <iterator>     // ostream_operator

#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;

    string data("input.txt");

    ifstream in(data.c_str());
    if (!in.is_open()) return 1;
    typedef tokenizer< escaped_list_separator<char> > Tokenizer;

    vector< string > vec;
    string line;

    while (getline(in,line))
    {
        Tokenizer tok(line);
        vec.assign(tok.begin(),tok.end());

        if (vec.size() < 1) continue;

        copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(),

             ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "-"));
        cout << "\n" << endl;
    }
}
```

Till now awesome. 
Output:

```
55.2-4-1-0-d-e-a
```

But I really couldn't figure it out how to save each token in array.
Ex:

```
a[0]=55.2
a[1]=4
a[2]=1
a[3]=0
a[4]=d
a[5]=e
a[6]=a
```

Edit:
May be the question was not clear. I want to parse the individual data and use it in other places so I need to save them as a array so that I can access them when ever I want.

Comment: What do you mean save each character in the array? You already have them all saved like that. That's what's in `vec`!

Comment: Not seeing a question. "Do it for me" "Give me hints & tips" "Guide me" are not questions.

Comment: Please tell us what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "saving" (nothing is saved anywhere)? Do you wish to create output like you indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is intrested.

```
cout  << vec[0] << endl;
```

It will display the first token. 
Thanks @Barry